# How to different size image resolution set and get export image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, renderer

I am new in `three js`. I get export image png format in `WebGL renderer`. it's working well. now I did attempt my export image `different custom size resolution`, and get my export image.My export image works well but resolution does not change. How to set `image resolution`?

```
var width,height,renderer3D;
renderer3D = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
               antialias: true,preserveDrawingBuffer: true
});

this.ExportImage = function(){
var imgSize = document.getElementById('imageSizeOption').value;
if(imgSize =='small'){    

            imgWidth = 640;
            imgHeight = 480;

}else if(imgSize =='medium'){

            imgWidth = 1024;
            imgHeight = 768;

}else if(imgSize =='large'){

            imgWidth = 1536;
            imgHeight = 1024;

}

        fileName = 'construction'+".png";
        var a = window.document.createElement("a");
        a.href = renderer3D.domElement.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
        a.style.width= imgWidth + 'px';    //resolution width 
        a.style.height= imgHeight + 'px';  //resolution height it's not work
        a.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to change the image size,

Try setting the width and height of the image using style of the element in following way.

```
var imgElement = document.getElementById('imageSizeOption')
imgElement.style.width = '640px';
imgElement.style.height = '480px';
```

Following is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/no94d8k8/)

Comment: `imgeSizeOption` this id is commbo box selection option mode (small, madium, large)@Vinit Divekar